# What responses does jQuery.ajax consider to be "success"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX post request that is unexpectedly triggering the `error` callback instead of `success`.  One random suspicion I have is the 302 status code it is receiving, although that may be wrong.

I looked at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but I feel like one thing is a bit unclear: What is jQuery's definition of a successful request?

Comment: I think that when there is HTTP 200 response.

Comment: if it's not a 4xx/5xx code, basically. 3xx it should just follow the redirect then work with the code the new url returns, 2xx means http success anyways.

Comment: I thinx 2xx and 3xx responses are success. But can't approve it.

Comment: what does your request look like? Does it expect a specific data type like JSON? If the JSON is malformed it may throw an error. Though the 302 is probably a good suspect considering the w3 spec for 302 states "If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued."

Comment: If the response is 2xx or 3xx AND the returned data matches the expected dataType and is valid, the response should be considered a success

Comment: 3xx is inaccurate, it's actually just 304, see James's answer.

Comment: For those who can't see my answer (now deleted) it pointed out a line of code (`if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 )`) from the jQuery source. But there's more to it than just the status code, as @KevinB stated previously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the response is between 199 and 300 ( >= 200 and < 300 ) or equal to 304 and the responseText can be successfully converted to the dataType that you provide (text by default), it is considered a successful request.

For example, if you return JSON and you get a 200 response status but it fails, it is more than likely a JSON parser problem meaning your JSON is not valid.

If you are returning HTML or XML and it fails with a 200 response status, the responsetext couldn't be converted to HTML or XML respectively (commonly happens in IE with invalid html/xml)

Comment: I tested it, and a plain status code of 302 results in an error.  It's probably best for simplicity's sake for affirmative responses to AJAX requests to always be 200s.

Comment: Very helpful! I looked up the exact code, the determination occurs within the [done](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d68b7877f761264bfe4950e4df156b854925a6b/src/ajax.js#L655) internal callback method.  Specifically: [status code check](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d68b7877f761264bfe4950e4df156b854925a6b/src/ajax.js#L683), [response parsing check](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d68b7877f761264bfe4950e4df156b854925a6b/src/ajax.js#L721)